# How to make "resident folder" to be the working directory?

Tags: r, directory, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting path of an R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452086/getting-path-of-an-r-script)

I am preparing an R-Script to set the working directory I put the following in ffront of all the other commands:

```
##### Set directory root                                                   
# --> Change this to resident folder of script!
setwd('I:/intern/projects/01.ongoing.projects/Data.rep.final/')
```

The path given in setwd() is  the "resident" folder of the script (-> the one where it has been saved).

If I put the script to another folder or if I move the containing folder I have to provide the new path to the script. Is there a better way of doing this? I presume that there is some function like get.saveD() that returns the location of the file, but so far I couldn't find it.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Best
Albrecht

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3452086/602276