# Set Working Directory to CD-ROM

Tags: r, working-directory, cd-rom

I have to hand in my R-program on CD-ROM. This CD-ROM should also contain the original datasets. To start the program, the working directory has to be set to load the datasets. Unfortunately, I do not know how to set the working directory to a specific CD-ROM, so that my supervisor can only run the program without having to modify anything. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: perhaps https://github.com/krlmlr/rprojroot will help?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: @hrbrmstr very instructing link, from what i understood it might solve the OP's problem if 1/ the `rprojroot` package is already installed, 2/ if the script and data are organised as an R project, is that right?

Comment: Aye. Though I believe it handles other types of dir structures too

Comment: @prznrl Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setwd](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html) function for this purpose or if you like to set it interactively, try `choose.dir` function within the `setwd`.

Answer (score 0):

I turned my comment into an answer:

You want an R script that can work just by clicking the Run button on a script located on a CD-ROM. The first idea is to start by defining the working directory with the drive letter commonly used for CD-ROMs:

```
setwd("E:/project/") # remember that in R the slash is inverted for the paths
```

However, the CD-ROM drive name can vary across the computers (D:, E:, ...) and it might not work. You could for instance use a prompt to ask for a user input like this (be careful because the behaviour can vary wether you run it as a whole, line by line, or source it):

```
CDROM <- readline(prompt = "Specify the letter of the CR-ROM drive: ")
setwd(paste0(CDROM, ":/project/"))
```

If you don't want any action from the user, there is a way for R to automatically find the repertory where the active script is located (see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452086/getting-path-of-an-r-script), you'll see that it's not as simple as it seems). It might work with the following line, but only if the user *sources* the script instead of running it:

```
setwd(dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile))
```

Personnally, I would simply add a comment line at the beginning of the script telling to click on the R-studio menu (most people use it):

*session > set working directory > to source file location*

Hope it helps!