# How to get the script path in R?

Tags: r, path, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rscript: Determine path of the executing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/rscript-determine-path-of-the-executing-script)

Always I run an R script, it take `My Documents` as working directory.

When I run the script, I want to get the script path and change the working directory to it. How I can do this?

I want this to run the scripts in same folder with the `source()` function.

Comment: If you use ESS there's a macro to do this. Probably for other editors too.

Comment: Perhaps:  `args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = F)  ; 
scriptPath <- dirname(sub("--file=","",args[grep("--file",args)]))`   From one of the answers in the above cited SO link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you run script by `source`, then try `source(file, chdir = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2):

What the hex, I try putting it in as a solution:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = F)
 scriptPath <- dirname(sub("--file=","",args[grep("--file",args)]))
```