# R: sourcing files using a relative path

Tags: r

Sourcing files using a relative path is useful when dealing with large codebases. Other programming languages have well-defined mechanisms for sourcing files using a path relative to the directory of the file being sourced into. An example is Ruby's [`require_relative`](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html). What is a good way to implement relative path sourcing in R?

Below is what I pieced together a while back using various recipes and R forum posts. It's worked well for me for straight development but is not robust. For example, it breaks when the files are loaded via the `testthat` library, specifically `auto_test()`. `rscript_stack()` returns `character(0)`.

```
# Returns the stack of RScript files
rscript_stack <- function() {
  Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(sys.frames(), function(x) x$ofile))
}

# Returns the current RScript file path
rscript_current <- function() {
  stack <- rscript_stack()
  r <- as.character(stack[length(stack)])
  first_char <- substring(r, 1, 1)
  if (first_char != '~' && first_char != .Platform$file.sep) {
    r <- file.path(getwd(), r)
  }
  r
}

# Sources relative to the current script
source_relative <- function(relative_path, ...) {
  source(file.path(dirname(rscript_current()), relative_path), ...)
}
```

Do you know of a better `source_relative` implementation?

Comment: Is the rscript_stack doing exactly what is described in the answers to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/rscript-determine-path-of-the-executing-script   ... or perhaps this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087743/how-to-get-the-script-path-in-r

Comment: You are absolutely right. In fact, I recall reading @Hadley's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/rscript-determine-path-of-the-executing-script and using the code. Ironic that it is testthat that the code doesn't work with.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

After a [discussion](https://github.com/hadley/test_that/issues/41) with @hadley on GitHub, I realized that my question goes against the common development patterns in R.

It seems that in R files that are sourced often assume that the working directory (`getwd()`) is set to the directory they are in. To make this work, `source` has a `chdir` argument whose default value is `FALSE`. When set to `TRUE`, it will change the working directory to the directory of the file being sourced.

In summary:

1. Assume that `source` is always relative because the working directory of the file being sourced is set to the directory where the file is.
2. To make this work, always set `chdir=T` when you source files from another directory, e.g., `source('lib/stats/big_stats.R', chdir=T)`.

For convenient sourcing of entire directories in a predictable way I wrote `sourceDir`, which sources files in a directory in alphabetical order.

```
sourceDir <- function (path, pattern = "\\.[rR]$", env = NULL, chdir = TRUE) 
{
    files <- sort(dir(path, pattern, full.names = TRUE))
    lapply(files, source, chdir = chdir)
}
```

Comment: @DanChaltiel: `read.csv(./) I guess that is what you're looking for