# How do I get in R the name of currently executed script when called via `r BATCH script file`

Tags: r, batch-file, filepath

I call a script from a shell command line with

```
r CMD BATCH myscript.R
```

What do I have to do in myscript.R to get a character vector with the name of the script (i.e. "myscript.R")?

#### Note:

I found numerous questions on *similar* topics, but couldn't find anything that work for me. Particularly from question [Determine path of the executing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/rscript-determine-path-of-the-executing-script) I got the modified script snippet:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = F)  
scriptPath <- sub("^--file=", "", args[grep("^--file=", args)])
```

but `scriptPath` is always empty (probably due to the way I call the script via the BATCH command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example with `commandArgs()` works fine for me:

`myscript.R`:

```
commandArgs()[3]
```

in the terminal:

```
R CMD BATCH myscript.R
```

and then `cat myscript.Rout`:

```
 commandArgs()[3]
[1] "myscript.R"
```

Comment: Works for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you use `Rscript` instead of `R CMD BATCH` it will work for you. I read the same post when I was trying to figure out how set working directory to directory of myscript. Anyway to run `Rscript`

`"....\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" Myscript.r > Myscript.r.rout`

And here is my code to set working directory to directory of script. I kept trying different alternatives to this then I realized you need to be using Rscript for the bulk of them to work.

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = F)  
scriptPath <- normalizePath(dirname(sub("^--file=", "", args[grep("^--file=", args)])))
setwd(scriptPath)
```