# Rcpp: how to keep files generated by sourceCpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I use `sourceCpp()` from the `Rcpp` package to build a C++ file and call it from R.  It seems to generate a temporary directory where it writes the source it compiles, but it removes that directory after building the code.  I want to get access to the exact file it is compiling, so that I can see it in my debugger.  How can I prevent `sourceCpp()` from deleting the file it compiles?

Answer (score 4):

I also love the flexibility of `sourceCpp` when doing academic researches. In many situations, writing a package is too much for our purposes. I have been using the following wrapper of `sourceCpp` which keeps the shared library.

```
importCpp <- function(infile, output_dir="lib", rebuild=FALSE){
    output_dir = ifelse(is.null(output_dir), ".", output_dir)
    dir.create(output_dir, recursive=T, showWarnings=FALSE)
    outfile = file.path(output_dir, paste0(infile, ".R"))

    if (!file.exists(outfile) || file.info(infile)$mtime > file.info(outfile)$mtime || rebuild){
        Rcpp::sourceCpp(infile, rebuild=rebuild)
        context = .Call("sourceCppContext", PACKAGE = "Rcpp",
            normalizePath(infile, winslash = "/"), code=NULL, 0L, .Platform)
        scriptfile = file.path(context$buildDirectory, context$rSourceFilename)
        content = readLines(scriptfile)
        ext = .Platform$dynlib.ext
        m = regexpr(paste0("(?<=dyn.load\\(').*", ext), content[1], perl=TRUE)
        shlibfile = file.path(output_dir, paste0(infile, ext))
        shlibfile0 = regmatches(content[1], m)
        content[1] = sub(shlibfile0, shlibfile, content[1])

        f = file(outfile, "w+")
        writeLines(content, f)
        close(f)
        file.copy(shlibfile0, shlibfile, overwrite=TRUE)
    }else{
        source(outfile)
    }
    invisible(outfile)
}
```

To use the code:

```
importCpp("foo.cpp")
```

If the file has not beed complied, the shared library and a R file `foo.cpp.R` will be copied to a folder `lib` under the current folder. However, if `lib\foo.cpp.R` is found, it would source the R file.

Also, if `foo.cpp` is modified, `importCpp` will recompile the `cpp` file if necessary.

Comment: This seems to be just what i'm looking for, but I keep getting `Error in importCpp("functions.cpp") : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=list; extent=8].` for the `context = ... ` line

Answer (score 3):

As Dirk said -- *seriously, just use packages*. Any other workflow you develop on top of `sourceCpp` is likely to be insufficient / annoying to use.

That said, `Rcpp` does not automatically delete the directory where source files are generated. Look at the output from `sourceCpp(..., verbose = TRUE)`:

```
> sourceCpp("~/scratch/save-source-cpp.cpp", verbose = TRUE)

Generated extern "C" functions 
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>

RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_2047_timesTwo(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    SEXP __sexp_result;
    {
        Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type x(xSEXP );
        int __result = timesTwo(x);
        PROTECT(__sexp_result = Rcpp::wrap(__result));
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return __sexp_result;
END_RCPP
}

Generated R functions 
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_2047_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T//RtmppARq3j/sourcecpp_1b612a59c474/sourceCpp_85891.so')

timesTwo <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function(x) {}, FALSE, `.sourceCpp_2047_DLLInfo`, 'sourceCpp_2047_timesTwo')

rm(`.sourceCpp_2047_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T//RtmppARq3j/sourcecpp_1b612a59c474

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_85891.so' 'save-source-cpp.cpp' 
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include  -I"/Users/kevin/Library/R/3.1/library/Rcpp/include"    -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -c save-source-cpp.cpp -o save-source-cpp.o
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_85891.so save-source-cpp.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

Note the `DIR:` line. If I look at what's within, I see:

```
> list.files("/var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T//RtmppARq3j/sourcecpp_1b612a59c474")
[1] "save-source-cpp.cpp"   "save-source-cpp.cpp.R" "save-source-cpp.o"     "sourceCpp_29322.so"
```

and if I read the (modified) cpp file, I see:

```
> cat(readLines("/var/folders/tm/5dt8p5s50x58br1k6wpqnwx00000gn/T//RtmppARq3j/sourcecpp_1b612a59c474/save-source-cpp.cpp"), sep = "\n")
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Below is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar)

// For more on using Rcpp click the Help button on the editor toolbar

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int timesTwo(int x) {
   return x * 2;
}


#include <Rcpp.h>

RcppExport SEXP sourceCpp_2047_timesTwo(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    SEXP __sexp_result;
    {
        Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< int >::type x(xSEXP );
        int __result = timesTwo(x);
        PROTECT(__sexp_result = Rcpp::wrap(__result));
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return __sexp_result;
END_RCPP
}
```

So all we do is generate the wrapper function using the `.Call` interface that can understand the regular function interface.

If you want to save that file somewhere, you could use `capture.output(sourceCpp(..., verbose = TRUE))` and then parse the `DIR:` output and go from there.

But seriously, just make a package.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I will try it out.  But please don't presume that R packages work for everyone, because they do not.  Maybe I will write a separate question about that someday.

Comment: I apologize. I am curious what your workflow entails such that packages are not satisfactory, though.

Comment: Here's a question I asked earlier about packages, which I answered myself with the code for the solution I made: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050275/make-r-package-easy-to-update-with-new-files-from-users - the general idea is that semi-professional developers need to be able to contribute to a shared repository of R code within my team, and packages are too hard for them (and honestly, me) to use productively.  We don't need to compile any code usually, and packages have the additional massive disadvantage of being installed per-R-version.  I hope this explains somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

Reactivating this question since it was not answered and it is still my googles first hit.

I have a C version of an R function saved in the file `f1.cpp`. What I (and the op) want is the result of `sourceCpp("f1.cpp")`, namely the file `f1.so` which is hidden in the temporary folder defined via the argument `cacheDir` of the function `sourceCpp`.

If, however, I set `cacheDir=/my/path` to a director of my choice, still, temporary directories are created and the result is not saved as `/my/path/f1.so` but as `/my/path/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.1/sourcecpp_2db138ae3a0c/sourceCpp_2.so`.

This is very cumbersome since now I have to

1. find and `mv /my/path/asd/asd/sourceCpp_2.so /my/path/f1.so`
2. add the rather complicated line to the R script where the C version of the function finally shall be used:

```
f1 <- Rcpp:::sourceCppFunction(function(arg1, arg2) {},
                               isVoid=F, dll=dyn.load("my/path/f1.so"),
                               symbol='sourceCpp_1_f1') # from the generated file f1.cpp.R
res <- f1(arg1, arg2)
```

3. Finally, I can add the well defined `/my/path` and all its content to the project I am working on (e.g. git*).

I dont see how "make a package" is an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Rcpp Attributes vignette about how to transition from one-off files for experimentation and exploration (which are compiled via `sourceCpp()` to organizing your files -- using the same technology -- in the way R prefers: as packages.

It is not hard, Rcpp Attributes helps you, and you will see the advantage in due course.  You could start via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` (see its help page) or copy from an existing package.

(As an aside, the temporary directory used by `sourceCpp()` is the same temporary directory used by the very R session you are in when you call `sourceCpp()`. We don't obfuscate any further.)

Comment: I tried using packages but found they were not a good fit for my work.  I don't think it's a good idea to get into all the reasons here and now; anyway the reason I want a way to not delete the source file is for debugging and profiling, or as you say, experimentation and exploration.

Comment: Nobody is deleting your _source_ files.

Comment: OK let me ask a related question: is the source file that sourceCpp compiles an exact copy from the filename I gave it, or does it preprocess the file somewhat?  If the file is identical I can tell my debugger to search the path of the original source, but if Rcpp is modifying the file contents before compiling, that won't work well (because line numbers won't match etc.).