# Command for "Set working directory to source file location"

Tags: r, rstudio, working-directory

RStudio has a useful feature:

```
Session -> Set Working Directory -> To Source File Location
```

Is there a way to do this without using the drop down menus?

UPDATE:

maybe a better way of asking is:

is there a command to return the file path of the current r script?

I also found this thread, but the solutions didn't work for me.  Not even Hadley's!

[Rscript: Determine path of the executing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/rscript-determine-path-of-the-executing-script)

Comment: This may help. Check ?setwd()

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
source("script.R", chdir = TRUE)
```

and change "script.R" by the name of the file you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, this is close! But suppose I have started a new R file and saved it to a location.  I then want to set the working directory to THAT file's location.  I can't source the file without knowing the path -- which is the very problem we're trying to solve automatically.

Comment: R help said about 'chdir': if TRUE and file is a **pathname**, the R working directory is temporarily changed to the directory containing file for evaluating.

Answer (score 1):

```
pathwd<-sub("/filename","",system("find -perm -g=w -type f -name 'filename'",intern=T)[1])
setwd(pathwd)
```

Make sure your file's name is unique.

Comment: > pathwd<-sub("/filename","",system("find -perm -g=w -type f -name 'filename'",intern=T)[1])
find: illegal option -- p
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
Warning message:
running command 'find -perm -g=w -type f -name 'filename'' had status 1

Comment: @AlexCoppock I would suggest that you might be using a Mac, and Ciro is on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on most systems, it gets a little buggy with Macs.

```
dir <- dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile)
setwd(dir)
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- I'm on a mac... `parent.frame(2)$ofile` is NULL for me.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on @Ciro's answer above, for Mac users:

```
pathwd<-sub("/dummy.R","",system("find . -type f -name dummy.R",intern=T)[1]) 
setwd(pathwd)
```

Replace `dummy.R` with your filename of course.