# Finding location of the current file

Tags: r, directory

My question is exactly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/rscript-determine-path-of-the-executing-script). I tried all the solutions listed there but they didn't work :(

Only difference is that I am not sourcing other R files. I am going to read csv files that are at the same location as the current R script.

I need this feature as that way I can transfer R file easily to other PCs/systems

I want that solution to work on Rstudio and command line and on Windows and Linux.

I would like to offer a bounty of 50 credits

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this to your script?

```
    currentpath <- getwd()
```

Then you can read the csv file `foo.csv` with

```
    read.csv(paste0(currentpath,'/','foo.csv'))
```

To make the code more platform independent you can explore the `normalizePath` function.

Comment: that doesnt work as my current file is not in the working directory :(