# How to check if a function has been called from the console?

Tags: r, environment-variables

I am trying to track the number of times certain functions are called from the console.
My plan is to add a simple function such as "trackFunction" in each function that can check whether they have been called from the console or as underlying functions.

Even though the problem sounds straight-forward I can't find a good solution to this problem as my knowledge in function programming is limited. I've been looking at the call stack and rlang::trace_back but without a good solution to this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to see on which level the current frame lies. That is, if a function is called directly in the interpreter, then `sys.nframe()` returns `1`, otherwise `2` or higher.

Relate:

> [Rscript detect if R script is being called/sourced from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932246/rscript-detect-if-r-script-is-being-called-sourced-from-another-script/47932989#47932989)

```r
myfunc <- function(...) {
  if (sys.nframe() == 1) {
    message("called from the console")
  } else {
    message("called from elsewhere")
  }
}

myfunc()
# called from the console

g <- function() myfunc()
g()
# called from elsewhere
```

Unfortunately, this may not always be intuitive:

```r
ign <- lapply(1, myfunc)
# called from elsewhere
for (ign in 1) myfunc()
# called from the console
```

While for many things the `lapply`-family and `for` loops are similar, they behave separately here. If this is a problem, perhaps the only way to mitigate this is the analyze/parse the call stack and perhaps "ignore" certain functions. If this is what you *need*, then perhaps this is more appropriate:

> [R How to check that a custom function is called within a specific function from a certain package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746607/r-how-to-check-that-a-custom-function-is-called-within-a-specific-function-from/62747050#62747050)

Comment: Hi r2evans, thanks for the detailed reply. What I meant with "called from the console" is any function called from there i.e if I run func1(func2(func3))) then I consider all 3 were run from the console. However sys.nframe() will return 1,2,3 respectively. Further issue is the pipe operator if I do "arg1" %>% func1 %>% func2 %>% func3  I also consider them called from the console and the sys.nframe() is even less reliable.  So I guess it has to come from the analysis of the first environment

Comment: Good luck, then. My only thought is following my second link, and broadening the list of acceptable packages/functions (since many of your calls from the console will have one or more parent/calling functions).