# How to instruct R to save ggplot in the same directory where the script is executed?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running a Rscript where I plot some X-Y data, and I want that plot to be saved in the same directory from where the script has been executed. I've found many solutions to this for `bash`, but couldn't figure it out for `R`.

```
# Raw data plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(X,Y)) + theme_bw()
  dev.print(file="Rplot.png", device=png, width=2800, res = 300)
```

I tried putting `"./Rplot.png"` but without success. I also though I could set the working directory as the current directory with `setwd` but actually couldn't figure out how to define the current directory.

This R script will be called within a bash script and it would be nice to have the graph in the same directory without having to define it every time.

Many thanks.
TP

Comment: Does `getwd()` work? Can you use `file.path(getwd(), "Rplot.plg")`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16046056/2375551

Answer (score 1):

Use getwd() to see where you're working.

Try

`ggsave(p, filename = "Rplot.png", width = 2800)`

to save the file where you have your working directory set to.
You can see all of the options with ?ggsave

Comment: For the future reference, this works as well and saves the plots in the directory where the script has been executed:

`png(filename="MyPlot.png")
p
dev.off()`