# Current path of an R script

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make available a shiny app for some people at work but I don't want to change the working directory manually for everyone. I had plan to use the `rstudioapi` function `getActiveDocumentContext()` but it only works when the app is lunch from rstudio and i'm using R console because the app is deployed with a .bat file (describe in this page http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3269_a6682dfda37e411fb5e0e6699495cdc4.html). I tried a bunch of the answers here ([Rscript: Determine path of the executing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/rscript-determine-path-of-the-executing-script)) but neither work, and most of them I don't understand so I was not able to "fix theme".

Comment: Are you guys using same LAN??  If so, then you can share direct URL of the shiny app.

Comment: we are not it is personal computers for each person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your linked SO question indicates, there are many solutions, my favorite is using `rprojroot` (I think it is probably the easiest). Using the simply shiny test_app example, you need to have this in your run.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rprojroot)
folder_address = dirname(thisfile())
runApp(folder_address, launch.browser=TRUE)
```

I tested it on a Mac with the start script (`test.command`) below, and it works wherever you have the test_app folder:

```
#! /bin/bash

PWD="`dirname \"$0\"`"
cd "${PWD}"
Rscript "run.R"
```

On a Windows computer, you'll need to specify the path to Rscript.exe (or R.exe) in your `test.bat`:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\Rscript.exe" "run.R"
```

Comment: I tried it but i keep getting the following error:  `Error in thisfile() : could not find function "thisfile"`. I installed the package `kimisc` which seems to be the one that has that function but then I got a lot of error messages saying I should use `rprojroot::` but it doesn't work. I don't know how relevant this is but i´m using R version 3.4.2 but the answer shouldn't depend on the R version.

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade Install the package `rprojroot` instead and I think version 3.4.2 should work.

Comment: I also installed that package and tried using the command you posted but it didn't work I got the error in the comment above thats why I tried with the package `kimisc` which then said that i should be using the package `rprojroot`

Comment: Do you have the `require(rprojroot)` line in your script?

Comment: obvious. What version of the package do you have because when I run `rprojroot::thisfile()` I get  `Error: 'thisfile' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rprojroot'` which means its not a primary function of the package. Also searching in the package help page theres no `thisfile()` function describe.

Comment: That's odd. Works for me:
`> packageVersion("rprojroot")`
[1] ‘1.3.2’
`> rprojroot::thisfile()`
NULL

Comment: An alternative is to copy the `thisfile_rscript` function from `thisfile.R` in the `rprojroot` package to your own script, and then use `thisfile_rscript()` in the place of `thisfile()` in your script: https://github.com/r-lib/rprojroot/blob/master/R/thisfile.R

Comment: I just copied that function and the result is `NULL` so it doesn't work in your answer

Comment: The result should be NULL when you call it in a R console. Put this line in your R script `print(thisfile_rscript())`, save and run it from a command line terminal: `Rscript run.R`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179500/discussion-between-lmw-and-alejandro-andrade).