# R get path of current script

Tags: r, path

I tried to use `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path` to get the current script path.

However, when I run `rscript myscript.r` in the dos command, it says, `Error: RStudio not running Execution halted`.

Any other methods?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/jennybc/here_here

Comment: I believe this question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/rscript-determine-path-of-the-executing-script

Answer (score 2):

Recently another package was developed called [this.path](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=this.path) to deal with this problem.  I've tried it and it works very well.