# Creating R script as an executable file .exe

Tags: r, exe

SO i want to execute a R script as an executable file, so I followed this tutorial. http://www.r-datacollection.com/blog/Making-R-files-executable/

And then configured it so that it would always open with the same program and so on.

Now the problem is that when I create the test file they provide, everything works fine, but as soon as i introduce a code such as

```
workd=dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)
```

the executing black panel closes down.

Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since you are not running RStudio, but rather `R` on its own, `rstudioapi::*` calls will fail. It looks like you want to get the system path of your script, the [`here` package](https://here.r-lib.org/)  can help you with that. Alternatively you could avoid using absolute paths and only use relative paths.

Comment: There is a script here that will find the path of the current file: gist.github.com/jasonsychau/ff6bc78a33bf3fd1c6bd4fa78bbf42e7

Comment: There's a "highly active question" that addresses this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815606/determine-path-of-the-executing-script and a package "this.path"